# SBT : Override behavior of task "test" to run only tests from default testSource folder, there are multiple test source folders

Tags: scala, sbt, typesafe-activator

We have standard SBT project with standard directory structure.

The ***test*** folder contains all the JUnit tests.

We introduced a new folder ***othertests*** and the folder ***othertests*** is peer to folder ***test***

The ***othertest*** folder contains some special test cases. The test classes names in the folder ***othertest*** can be easily distinguished from the normal JUnit tests.

Below is my working build.sbt configuration.

I have added the folder ***othertest*** in test sources using `javaSources in Test` SBT task.

We are using ***activator*** to run tests and do other stuff.

When I run `activator> test` I want all tests from the folder ***test***  only to run and I want to run tests from the folder ***othertests*** separately.

Questions.

1. How to override the behavior of test tasks to filter out tests from the folder ***othertests***
2. Should I create shared modules to run normal junit tests separately and other junit tests separately.

Below is my build.sbt configuration

```
import java.io.PrintStream

import play.sbt.PlayJava
import play.twirl.sbt.Import._

name := "Service"

version := "5.1.0"

scalaVersion := "2.11.8"

routesGenerator := InjectedRoutesGenerator

lazy val ContractTest = config("contract") extend(Test)

def contractTestFilter(name: String): Boolean = name endsWith "ContractTest"

def ignoreContractTest(name: String): Boolean = !contractTestFilter(name)

lazy val root = (project in file("."))
  .enablePlugins(PlayJava)
  .configs(ContractTest)
    .settings(
      inConfig(ContractTest) (Defaults.testTasks),
      javaSource in Test := { (baseDirectory in Test) (_ / "contracttest") }.value,
      testOptions in ContractTest := Seq(Tests.Filter(contractTestFilter),Tests.Argument(TestFrameworks.JUnit, "-q", "-v", "-s")),
      testOptions in Test := Seq(Tests.Filter(ignoreContractTest),Tests.Argument(TestFrameworks.JUnit, "-q", "-v", "-s"))
    )

lazy val xyz = taskKey[Unit]("custom task to create loglayout jar file under lib folder")

xyz := {
  LogLayoutJar.build(scalaBinaryVersion.value, streams.value.log)
}

run := (run in Runtime).dependsOn(xyz).evaluated

javaOptions in Test ++= Seq("-Dconfig.resource=applic.tt.cnf")

libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  json,
  javaWs,
  "org.mockito" % "mockito-all" % "1.10.19" % Test,
  "org.scalatestplus.play" %% "scalatestplus-play" % "1.5.1" % Test,
  "org.easytesting" % "fest-assert" % "1.4" % Test,
  "org.scalactic" %% "scalactic" % "2.2.0",
  "org.jmockit" % "jmockit" % "1.9" % Test,
  "com.portingle" % "slf4jtesting" % "1.0.0" % Test,
  "org.scalacheck" %% "scalacheck" % "1.12.6" % Test
)

resolvers ++= Seq(
  "Typesafe repository" at "http://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/releases/"
)

parallelExecution in Test := runningTestInParallel

testGrouping in Test := groupByModule((externalDependencyClasspath in Test).value,
  (definedTests in Test).value, streams.value.log)

javacOptions ++= Seq(
  "-Xlint:unchecked",
  "-Xlint:deprecation"
)
scalacOptions ++= Seq(
  "-feature",
  "-language:implicitConversions",
  "-deprecation"
)

// Custom tasks //
val silenceSystemErr = taskKey[Unit]("Replaces System.err with a PrintStream to nowhere.")

silenceSystemErr := {
  System.setErr(new PrintStream(new DevNull))
  println("Messages System.err will not be printed.")
}

val restoreSystemErr = taskKey[Unit]("Restores the original System.err")

restoreSystemErr := {
  System.setErr(systemErr)
  println("Messages System.err will be printed.")
}
```

From jenkins we run tests using below command -

```
bin/activator -Dsbt.log.noformat=true -Denvironment_name=test -DsuppressLogging=true clean silenceSystemErr jacoco:cover
```

Thank You
Rakesh

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1.

You're contradicting yourself. Why add `javaSources in Test` if you don't want them to run when you run the `Test` command?

What you should do is create an [Additional Test configuration|http://www.scala-sbt.org/0.13/docs/Testing.html#Additional+test+configurations] that extends `Test` and runs only tests inside your `othertests` folder.

2.

You can create another module. I personally don't like this idea because then I have to name the module according to what it tests and I have 2 separate modules that should actually only be one.

A separate test module might be a good idea if you have some dependencies in your tests that slow down the overall build time of your module. For example imagine a Java project with Gatling performance tests. If the performance tests are in the same module then whenever I `rebuild` it it will also `rebuild` the gatling tests that require the scala compiler which is slower.

Some people can live with this, I'm one of them. I prefer to have the tests in the same project and possibly suffer a time penalty when rebuilding the module. Which rarely happens I create different test configurations when needed.

Another reason to choose separate modules for tests is when your tests depend on multiple modules and you don't want this module dependency at compile time for the `src` code.

Some IDE's and/or languages might encourage the use of separate module for tests as I understand is the case for C# and Visual Studio (but I might be wrong here, don't take my word for it).

Comment: Thank you @pedromss. Your suggestion is useful and I was able to achieve what I wanted. I am sharing my configuration so it is useful for others too. I am able to create a custom test configuration and able to filter all the required tests. However post configuration changes I am seeing 1 side effect in terms of the logs generated in our jenkins build. Can you please help as to why the extra logs are generated. My build.sbt file configuration is given in the new comment below.

Comment: I have edited my question to add the working build.sbt file.

Comment: One different log that I am seeing in the jenkins logs is - `[DEBUG] [09/12/2017 03:02:52.467] [application-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-2] [EventStream] shutting down: StandardOutLogger started`. It says that `StandardOutLogger` started. Could this be a reason why I am seeing all the unnecessary logs.

Comment: Seeing as your logs come from akka I would say it has nothing to do with sbt. Look in the akka documentation for how to tune log or lower the log level